# Windows 10 Anniversary center file and folder name text

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Anniversary update changed the alignment of the text for file and folder names to the left. It looks like this:

[image]

This looks really ugly to me and was wondering if there was any way to center the text as it was before the update. It gets even worse if it's a long word.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is solved in 1709 version (Creators Update).

Edit.

If the Creators update cannot be applied, then add below registry.

Easy way to apply the registry is as follows.

1. Make a notepad file. ex) a.txt
2. Copy it into a.txt
3. Change a.txt as a.reg
4. Execute :)

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
>   "KnownFolderDerivedFolderType"="{57807898-8C4F-4462-BB63-71042380B109}"
>   "SniffedFolderType"="Generic" "FolderType"="NotSpecified"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
>   "FFlags"=dword:43000000 "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
>   "Mode"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}]
>   "FFlags"=dword:43000000 "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
>   "Mode"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}]
>   "FFlags"=dword:43000000 "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
>   "Mode"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}]
>   "FFlags"=dword:43000000 "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
>   "Mode"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}]
>   "FFlags"=dword:43000000 "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
>   "Mode"=dword:00000001

Comment: Can you provide some more information to substantiate this? A link to a reputable source? A screen shot?

Comment: Thx for all the feedbacks :)